# Match BOL and EOL with std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost, std

```
std::string string("0");
std::regex pattern("^0$",std::regex_constants::extended);
bool match(std::regex_match(string,pattern));
```

I believe `^` and `$` must match the BOL and EOL respectively. Thus `match` is expected to be `true` but is actually `false`. Am I missing something?

[gcc-4.8.1 live demo](http://ideone.com/gKZm5o).

Comment: Which compiler? `std::regex` is not implemented in g++ afaik. And in most flavors `^`/`$` matches start/end of string unless the multiline flag/setting is used.

Comment: @Qtax I believe it is implemented in gcc-4.8.1. Provided a live demo link in the post.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean that it's fully implemented and working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libstdc++ has no full support for regex (you can check it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)).
I'm tried to compile this code with clang 3.2 with libc++-3.2 and result is "true". Use libc++, or boost.

Especially libstdc++ regex implementation status

```
8   Regular expressions
28.1    General N    
28.2    Definitions N    
28.3    Requirements    N    
28.4    Header <regex> synopsis N    
28.5    Namespace std::regex_constants  Y    
28.6    Class regex_error   Y    
28.7    Class template regex_traits Partial  
28.8    Class template basic_regex  Partial  
28.9    Class template sub_match    Partial  
28.10   Class template match_results    Partial  
28.11   Regular expression algorithms   N    
28.12   Regular expression Iterators    N    
28.13   Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar  N
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I wonder, which section does those tokens implementation belong? `28.1 General` probably? And gosh why don't they throw kind on `not_implemented_yet` exception...

Comment: @Kolyunya have no idea. For example for \\d regex it throws std::regex_error.